TCP source port sharing
My understanding of TCP connection is that a source PORT remains exclusive to one connection, no matter the destination is, so the number of connections from local port 12345 for example can never exceed 1.
I recently read that a TCP connection is identified by <src IP, src PORT, dst IP, dst PORT>

TCP allows source port sharing across multiple processes, but each
process requires a free port to bind to for its connection

so I went to validate that "port sharing across processes": this must mean that the same source port can be used to connect to different destinations.
However, when experimenting this, I tried these two commands:
nc -v -p 12345 google.com 80

which works well (-v for verbose, and -p to specify the source port as 12345, for my learning purpose)
Now, simultaneously running this command on a different shell
nc -v -p 12345 github.com 80

fails with this error message:

nc: connectx to github.com port 80 (tcp) failed: Address already in use

the reason I specified the same source port with -p is to validate that a source port can be shared. There's no need for this practically, in real-world scenario I would not even worry about source port. According to this, is it true that a source port will be only used once?

Another (at least) Linux oddity is as a normal user you can bind to every ephemeral port over UDP and TCP providing you have enough file descriptors and finish the connect. This denies every other user network connectivity. A standard netstat or ss wont reveal what happened, but lsof implicitly shows the problem.

There is no reason why two processes cannot use the same source port, as long as they do not both connect to the same destination (host, port). On many UNIX systems, set the SO_REUSEPORT option to enable processes to share a port number; on Windows, set SO_REUSEADDR. For example, with socat:

process 1: socat stdio tcp:google.com:80,bind=:12345,reuseport
process 2: socat stdio tcp:bing.com:80,bind=:12345,reuseport

These two processes can run simultaneously, and will both have source port 12345 (as you can confirm with netstat).
Note, however, that you will almost certainly run into issues if the sockets are not closed cleanly on both ends, as unclosed TCP sockets will enter a TIME_WAIT state which will cause the four-tuple (srcaddr, srcport, dstaddr, dstport) to be tied up until the wait period expires. Therefore, when using a single source port for multiple connections, you cannot reconnect to the exact same server & port unless the previous connection has fully shut down or the TIME_WAIT period has expired.

There are other gotchas with this behaviour when connecting out, such as the same UID needs to be used for all connects. Also SO_REUSEPORT is not a default option and has to be enabled on every socket.

The same UID has to be used to create & bind the sockets, yes. If you want to get really fancy, you can send the bound sockets over to some other process via SCM_RIGHTS or via fork inheritance, to enable processes with distinct UIDs to connect using the same bound sockets. Of course, you would have to have a really good reason for doing such a crazy thing...

AFAIK, SO_REUSEPORT can only be used with UDP sockets. And SO_REUSEADDR can only be used with a listening TCP socket, not outgoing sockets (the main purpose is to allow restarting the server while there are TIME_WAIT connections left over from the old server).

@Barmar: just try my code, it works on Linux and Mac at least (which is what I have access to). SO_REUSEPORT absolutely works with TCP sockets.

I guess it's evolved since I was doing network programming. I remember when the main use of it was so you could have multiple processes listening on the same multicast port.

The socket(7) manpage linked in my answer explicitly points out load-balancing as one use-case for REUSEPORT on TCP sockets. Linux even provides SO_ATTACH_REUSEPORT_EBPF to customize exactly how incoming connections are assigned to listening sockets. However, the use-cases for reusing source ports are much more narrow, even if it is doable.

It is interesting that for a listening socket some implementations of nc always set SO_REUSEPORT and SO_REUSEADDR. See How netcat can listen to the same port on the same host from two different terminals?, How to make nc listen on a port without setting SO_REUSEPORT IMHO both the options were mainly designed for listening sockets.

Any port is only ever allocated to a single process at any point in time. That process can create any number of connections with it, with the restriction that the destination IP address or port number must vary between connections.
As an example, TCP 10.0.0.10:49152 can connect only once to TCP 10.0.0.2:80 but can at the same time connect to TCP 10.0.0.3:80 or TCP 10.0.0.2:8080.

This is just not true on any major platform (at least Windows and UNIX/Linux). Processes can absolutely share ports; on Windows, set SO_REUSEADDR on subsequent binds to the same port, and on Linux/UNIX, set SO_REUSEPORT on every bind to the same port. It is only the default behaviour in which a port is allocated to a specific process.

SO_REUSEADDR can be used to quickly reopen a port just closed or in closing, but it cannot be used to share a port between arbitrary processes.

SO_REUSEADDR can be used on Windows to share a port between two processes. SO_REUSEPORT can be used on UNIX/Linux to share ports between processes. See my answer for more details.

You can just pass a socket between processes and thus any numbers of processes can share a port this way and create new connections. There is nothing in modern unix systems (and prtobably older ones, too) that would somehow associate a port with a specific process only.

A correct answer should point out that TCP only limits the number of 4-tuples (2x address, 2x port) to one, and that both sides of a connection are simultenously source and destination ports, as TCP/IP has no fixed client/server roles.

This answer would benefit from mentioning which OSes it applies on. Right now, it reads as if this non-sharing would be some natural property of TCP (or UDP), while I don't think the networking standards specify OS-level things like processes at all. Of course the OS has to figure out where to make the data available in userland, but I think on most systems, network connections are tied to sockets or other such handles, and not to processes directly (esp. since a process can often handle more than one connection at the same time).

This answer is plainly wrong. As a trivial example, any TCP server process usually opens one single port and accepts multiple connections, then forks another process to handle that connection, resulting in multiple processes sharing one port (but towards various remotes). This is the usual method to implement a TCP service.

While the TCP protocol itself allows arbitrary combinations of local and remote ports and addresses, most Unix implementations simplify port management. The reason is that the process of setting up sockets is split into separate steps.

First you set the local port with bind(). This step is required when creating a listening TCP socket (you have to specify what port it's listening on), it's optional before making an outgoing connection with connect() (an arbitrary local port will be assigned). Since we don't know the remote address or port yet, it's not possible to tell whether this is fully unique. So it simply checks whether the requested port is available. If the socket has the SO_REUSEADDR option set, it ignores connected  sockets when checking whether the local address is in use, but it will still fail if there's a listening socket on the port.

Then for an outgoing connection you call connect(), specifying the remote address. You can only call connect() once on a socket, and because we checked the local port during bind(), this can never produce a duplicate local/remote address/port.

For an incoming connection, you call accept() on the listening socket. Again, because we check that the local port of the listening socket is unused when we bind it, there can never be a duplicate combination.


Delaying the port checks until we have the remote information would complicate error handling. The current design just checks for duplication in one place: bind().

Slight point of clarification: bind() is not necessary when creating a listening socket. If you don’t call bind before listen, or you call bind with a zero port, a random ephemeral port will be assigned (which can be retrieved with getsockname). This can be used, for example, to create a service when there is no guarantee of any specific port being available.

Good point, that's how the FTP data connection is usually created. But just as with connect(), the random port will be chosen so it doesn't conflict with any other local port in use, since you don't know yet what remote ports will connect to it.

After some investigations I found that source port sharing is only allowed for multiple outgoing connections from the same process. The operating system needs to know which process to forward the connection stream to.
Going to select this answer in two days as the site policy.

This is a limitation of the particular network stack (embedded in the Linux kernel) and not the tcp/ip protocol in general. You can pretty much share a source port even in Linux by using some iptables nat trickery.

This is not accurate. What you are describing is a traditional model, such as for outgoing SMTP connections. TCP port sharing is platform dependent and implementation dependent. For example, .NET has an implementation of it.

"Going to select this answer in two days as the site policy." The delay isn’t just there to inconvenience you but to give time for other answers that you haven’t considered to come in. Notably, this answer is completely wrong, both in the described status quo and justification! Please select a correct answer instead!

I'm going to pitch in from another perspective: running out of source ports when you have a high connect/disconnect rate, because of TIME_WAIT.
First note: TIME_WAIT is not affected by tcp_fin_timeout. Instead, it's hard-coded at 60s. tcp_fin_timeout is for the other side.
For example, if you have a webserver that handles 1000 requests per second, and your webserver has the unfortunate, but yet frequently used, model of 'start code in worker/do stuff/end' (like PHP FPM), every request will open and close a connection to the database. This results in 60000 ports to the database in TIME_WAIT, as per the hard-coded 60s. This is too many and you get 'cannot assign requested address'.
All that talk about SO_REUSEPORT is pointless, because you have no control over that in the mysql connector. Plus, if you also have other processes, running as a different UID, you can't share.
The PHP MySQL driver does not support source address selection, like curl does.
So, the solution would be to add more IPs to the machine, and use haproxy for instance to rotate source address:
# Way to avoid the TIME_WAIT issue (running out of ports on our source
# address), by rotating over our source IPs
frontend mysqlfront
  mode tcp
  bind 127.0.0.1:3306
  default_backend mysqlback

# Way to avoid the TIME_WAIT issue (running out of ports on our source
# address), by rotating over our source IPs
backend mysqlback
  mode tcp
  balance leastconn
  server mysql_s1 server.com:3306 source 172.31.7.124
  server mysql_s2 server.com:3306 source 172.31.12.99

